# How to merge two seperate dataframes with uneven rows in R

Tags: r, merge

What is the easiest way to combine two separate `data.frame`s when one `data.frame` contains more rows than the other? Here is what I have:

```
Dataframe A
Customer ID      Items sold         Price
1                 20                 2.50
2                 30                 10.00
3                 40                 15.00
4                 NA                 1.00
5                 NA                 1.00

Dataframe B
customer Id       Items bought
1                  10
2                  NA 
3                  3
```

Comment: Putting spaces in column names is a really bad idea. Don't do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `merge`

```
merge(A, B, by.x='Customer.ID', by.y='customer.Id', all=TRUE)
```